# Passing prop from child to parent is null

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm pretty new to React Native and working on learning how to build apps with it. I have a child component that is created immediately when the app is opened.

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.state.buses.length; i++){
    bus = this.state.buses[i]
    busMarkers.push(
    <BusMarker  
        company={bus.company}
        latitude={bus.location.latitude}
        longitude={bus.location.longitude}
        title={"Bus " + bus.routeNumber}
        description={"This bus is from " + bus.company}
        getThisRoute={this.getRouteLine} //this is the function i want to call when the busMarker is pressed
        markerRouteID={bus.routeID} //trying to give it the usable property here
     />
     )
}
```

The bus.routeID is what I need to be able to use later. This is my BusMarker Component.

```
export default class BusMarker extends Component{
    handleClick = () => {
        routeID = this.props.markerRouteID
        this.props.getThisRoute(routeID)
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <MapView.Marker
                coordinate={{latitude: this.props.latitude, longitude: this.props.longitude}}
                title={this.props.title}
                description={this.props.description}
                image={busImg}
                onPress={this.handleClick}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

I want to be able to press on the BusMarker Icon, get the routeID, and pass it to the parent to be used to execute a particular function.

```
getRouteLine = (routeID) => {
    this.setState({markerRouteID: routeID})
    console.log("Route ID is: " + this.state.markerRouteID)
    //need to do more stuff here.
}
```

At this point, the code *works*, but in the console output above, it says that the this.state.markerRouteID is *null*. So I'm not sure how this is supposed to work. I've done enough research to know that doing .bind() isn't the best idea and that passing through props is the way to go. I've seen a lot of posts about passing static data from child to parent and vice versa. But this has thrown me through a loop and I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

**EDIT**: I got it working with the answer below, but I thought I would post what I arrived to.
This is my BusMarker Class that I was performing an action on (onPress)

```
export default class BusMarker extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <MapView.Marker
                coordinate={{latitude: this.props.latitude, longitude: this.props.longitude}}
                title={this.props.title}
                description={this.props.description}
                image={busImg}
                onPress={() => this.props.getThisRoute(this.props.markerRouteID)}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

This was where I was intializing the BusMarker Component in the Parent.

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.state.buses.length; i++){
    bus = this.state.buses[i]
    busMarkers.push(
    <BusMarker  
        company={bus.company}
        latitude={bus.location.latitude}
        longitude={bus.location.longitude}
        title={"Bus " + bus.routeNumber}
        description={"This bus is from " + bus.company}
        getThisRoute={this.getRouteLine} //this is the callback function i want to call when the busMarker is pressed
        markerRouteID={bus.routeID} 
     />
     )
}
```

This was the function I wanted called when BusMarker was pressed. It is located in the parent. It sets the state of the routeLineCoordinates.

```
getRouteLine(routeID){
    apiCalls.getRoute(routeID).then(results => {
        location = JSON.parse(results)
        this.setState({routeLineCoordinates: location})
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("Something went wrong getting Route Line: " + error)
    })
}
```

The parent constructor then needed this:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        routeLineCoordinates: [],
        markerRouteID: null
    }
    this.getRouteLine = this.getRouteLine.bind(this) 
}
```

And finally a function called in my render function

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
                style={styles.map}
                showsUserLocation={true}
                showsMyLocationButton={true}
                initialRegion={this.state.region}
            >
            {this.addBusMarkers()}
            {this.addRouteLine()} //function that uses the changed state from the getRouteLine above
            </MapView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: I haven't used react native, but this.setState is asynchronous so to see state after it's set, put console.log in a callback after `this.setState({markerRouteID: ...}, () => console.log())`. Also you're calling the parent getThisRoute, but it looks like it's called getRouteLine. Hope this helps

Comment: So getThisRoute is the prop that calls getRouteLine. Like I said it reaches that parent function, but it is null. I'll try the  function notation you have though.

Comment: Post your parent component as well. Have you bind the function in parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your function in constructor. (in parent component)

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props) 
    this.yourFunction = this.yourFunction.bind(this)
}
```

And no, binding is necessary. It's just you must not bind the function inside render since it gets called multiple times.

Comment: ok i'll look at that. Thanks. Does the getRouteLine function need to look any different? I don't really understand the syntax of it.

Comment: You just need to pass a callback to setState and then console the log. Since setState is an async function